# Does C++ have following type of for loops or some way to do it with templates?

Tags: c++

Let r1,r2,r3 ... rn be sequence integers.  We want to iterate as follows through all r values.

foreach r in r1,r2 ... rn.

Comment: c++11 have something like you want : ranged-based for loop (http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html) => `for(auto i: { 1, 2, 3 }) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks that works.  You should have made it answer.

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with an ordinary `for` loop. I'm assuming the history lesson was to cheat a character limit, which probably indicates you didn't put enough effort into the question.

Comment: @steviekm3, you were downvoted because (I assume) you could have performed a search on google and found out (this is basics of C++ syntax).

Comment: Likely combination of that and Shakespeare text at end.  However such a google search is not that easy to get to bring up what is wanted.  I tried some and got all sorts of stuff mainly on iterating through containers.   I didn't see that good answer Garf365 gave.

Comment: in some sense, the answer Garf365 gave is a special case of iterating through a container. And even without a ranged based for loop your problem can be solved trivially by iterating through a container.

Comment: @steviekm3, ["iterating a sequence c++"](https://www.google.be/search?q=iterating+a+sequence+c%2B%2B&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&safe=active&gws_rd=cr&ei=cxnQVubZFcX5UpW4q5AM) - in the first result (which is [on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480394/c-stl-iterate-through-everything-in-a-sequence)) you will find all ways of iterating through a sequence in C++.

Comment: I just looked at your link and did not see the answer by Garf365.  There was answer about iterating through container which is close.  But I didn't see the non-variable way Garf365 gave.

Answer (score 1):

c++11 have something like you want : ranged-based for loop (http://cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html) => `for(auto i: { 1, 2, 3 }) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::reference_wrapper along with the range based for loop.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    int a = 0; 
    int b = 1; 
    int c = 2; 

    for ( auto x : { a, b, c } ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    int i = 10;
    for ( auto r : { std::ref( a ), std::ref( b ), std::ref( c ) } ) r.get() = i++;

    for ( auto x : { a, b, c } ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 1 2 
10 11 12
```